# Trying to create a list of random variables without repetition in Python 3, can't get it to work

Tags: python

sorry if the issue seems kind of simple, i'm fairly new to coding. Im trying to create a loop that prints 3 randomly selected responses and saves the value of those responses to a list, whilst also making sure that the same question isn't asked twice.

I tried to use boolean expressions to check if a element of the temporary random response list was also in the saved variables list and then restart the loop after removing said element, but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
from random import randrange

response1 = "1"
response2 = "2"
response3 = "3"
response4 = "4"
response5 = "5"
response6 = "6"
response7 = "7"
response8 = "8"
query = "q"
responses = [response1, response2,response3,response4,response5,response6,response7,response8]
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
print(query)
variables = []
randresponses = []
for i in range(3):
    counter += 1
    print(str(i+1) + ")")
    randresponses.append(responses[randrange(8)])
    if randresponses[0] in variables == True:
        randresponses.pop()
        counter -= 1
        continue
    else:
        variables.append(randresponses[0])
        print(randresponses[0])
        randresponses.pop()
        if i == 3:
            break
```

any ideas on how to get just a list of non repeating variables whilst still printing those same variables? Cheers for any help

Comment: How does your expected output look like? Perhaps you should try removing ```==True```

Comment: tried that, the outcome is instead of repeated numbers, i get an absence of numbers.
so instead of 3,3,2 as an output, i get 3,2

Comment: Then can you provide your expected output?

Comment: yeh sure, just edited the comment

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is static and is executed 3 times, regardless of the value of `counter`. Instead, you should do something like

```
while len(variables) < 3:
    r = responses[randrange(8)]
    if r not in variables:
        variables.append(r)
```

However, `random` already has a function for you to select k unique elements from an iterable.

```
variables = random.sample(responses, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. Using the random.choice() you can pass three random responses from your list. you can also add additional checks as well

```
import random
val = True

while val:
    res = random.choices(responses,k=3)
    if len(set(res))< 3:
        continue 
    val = False
else:
    print(res)
```